# Why does my functions.php keep crashing (wordpress)? - new to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using wordpress. Within functions.php, I am trying to add the following piece of code

```
function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( A53 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('a53wx2.js', '', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

When I add this, it is fine. However, when I try and add another function, similar to the one above, it crashes the site. This is the code which crashes the site:

```
<?php
}
add_filter( 'get_comments_number', 'blankslate_comment_count', 0 );
function blankslate_comment_count( $count ) {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
global $id;
$get_comments = get_comments( 'status=approve&post_id=' . $id );
$comments_by_type = separate_comments( $get_comments );
return count( $comments_by_type['comment'] );
} else {
return $count;
}
}
function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( A53 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('a53wx2.js', '', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
}
function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( A5004 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('a5004wx2.js', '', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

Which is the correct way to add the second function so that it does not crash the site? Thank you

Comment: is there a reason why you've repeated load_js_assets()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function name should be unique this will throw cann't redeclare function error so you need to change your function name

```
 function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( A53 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('a53wx2.js', 'http://peakweathereye.co.uk/a53wx2.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');

function load_js_assets1() {
    if( is_page( A5004 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('a5004wx2.js', 'http://peakweathereye.co.uk/a5004wx2.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets1');
```

Comment: And it might be worth to point out that there should be a big fat "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare <function>” error that might give you a hint. And if there isn't one, then your first problem should be how to configure your error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Your are loading the same function 'load_js_assets' twice.